# How to target multi platform - vue cli plugin electron builder

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to build my veu electron app using electron builder. I want to target macOS and windows with a portable release, anyway after click on `electron:build` option in vue ui, it will only create the dmg for macOS. Here is my `vue.config.js` file. I'm not very experienced with electron builder, can anyone help me?

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      outputDir: 'build',
      builderOptions: {
        mac: {
          target: 'dmg',
          icon: 'build/icon.icns',
          asar: true
        },
        win: {
          target: 'portable',
          icon: 'build/icon.icns',
          asar: true
        }
      },
      preload: 'src/preload.js'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer for this. Generally, you can only build your app for the platform you are on. There are some exceptions to the rule that are shown in the [documentation](https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build).

It seems the best way for you to do this would be to use a [docker image](https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build#provided-docker-images) such as `electronuserland/builder:wine` via [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/).

After installing Docker for Mac, you should be able to use the steps provided in the [docs](https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build#build-electron-app-using-docker-on-a-local-machine).

Comment: Thabk you for the tip. I've found a dirty solution to build for windows. I've installed `electron-installer-windows` and after instructed from vue ui the electron builder plugin to create macOS and windows build, I'm passing the resulting folder with windows unpacked build to the cli of electron-installer-windows. This will produce a `.nupkg` and an `.exe` file that can be used on windows.

Comment: That's a really cool idea. It eliminates the need for docker if you don't use it

Comment: Thank you. I hope that the problems with `electron-builder` to build NSIS windows installers are fixed soon.